# batch file 'for' and appending confusion

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to make a routine in my batch file that will append a call to itself to the beginning of every other batch file in every other drive (including flash drives and such). I've been using nested FOR functions to do this. The first part sets up a variable, called append, to do the actual appending to every batch file in the drive. The second part uses fsutil to get every drive in use and cascades each output through 'cd' then calls the append variable to do the actual appending. the intent is to make sure every drive is checked for batch files to be appended.
can I set a variable to be a string of commands like this?
will so many FOR functions create malfunctions, since I have one embedded in another?
Am I going about setting variables and using tokens in the FOR functions right?
will the actual appending process go smoothly?
and finally, will there be any interruptions that could interrupt automation, like trying to set cd to a disc drive with no disc in it and causing a "insert disc" popup?

```
set append = (
    FOR %%F IN (*.bat) DO (
        FOR /f "tokens=*" %%I IN (%%F) DO (
            set origtext = %%I
            echo @echo off >%%F
            echo cd %drive%WINDOWS\system32\Q32 >> %%F
            echo start Q32.bat >> %%F
            echo %%I >> %%F
        )
    )
)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN (fsutil fsinfo) DO (
    cd %%A
    %append%
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do less looping with something like this:

```
set desiredCall=c:\windows\batchyouwanttocall.bat

for /r %i in (*.bat) do (
   echo %desiredCall% > "%i.tmp"
   type "%i" >> "%i.tmp"
   move /y "%i.tmp" "%i"
)
```

`FOR /R` walks the directory tree from wherever you call it.  So if you run this from `C:`, every .bat file on your C drive will be affected.

Using this approach, you don't have to loop over every line of each file.  Just each file.

And to answer your question, I don't think you can set a variable to be a string of commands like that.

Something to watch for is that if the routine you want to call, `%desiredCall%` above, is also a .bat file, you'll want to make sure you don't set it up to call itself infinitely.

Comment: how do I circumvent the appending of the file to itself?

Comment: @user1374083, One way would be to rename it with a ".cmd" extension.  It'll still execute like a .bat that way, but it won't get caught up in your script.

Comment: I think I fixed it- I set the program to make a second text file and print its own contents into that text file, then when the appending is done, it copies the original text back into the program and deletes the text file. Will this work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but it sounds like you have a sense of what you're doing.  You just need to make sure that the call you want to make to `batchyouwanttocall.bat` doesn't get prepended to `batchyouwanttocall.bat` itself.  Does the answer I entered above suit you as an acceptable one?